# Change in URL is working but route change is not happeningin Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-routerlink

Url is changing like expected in while clicking but that particular route is not getting loaded. Please find the below code for reference.

**HTML**

```html
<a
  mat-tab-link
  *ngFor="let routeLink of routeLinks; let i = index"
  [routerLink]="routeLink.link"
  [routerLinkActive]="'mat-tab-link-active'"
  #rla="routerLinkActive"
  class="mat-tab-link"
>
  {{ routeLink.label }}
</a>
```

**TS**

```js
const path = `/site/`;
this.routeLinks = [
  {
    key: 'network',
    link: path + 'network'
  },
  {
    key: 'subnets',
    link: path + 'subnets'
  }
];
```

Comment: There is no routerLink attribute. Also, `index: this.routeLinks.length` within the assignment to `routeLinks` seems wrong.

Comment: It is there i missed to added in question. <div class="content"><router-outlet></router-outlet></div>. Even i removed the index too and verified no luck!

Comment: Thats the router outlet. routerLink should be an attribute on the anchor tag: `<a routerLink="foo">`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My component has multiple **router-outlet** in the parent component. The code snippet I shared is the child component so, the router is not working as expected. Finally, I understood the root cause I added the outlet to the router-outlet like below in the parent component resolves my issue.
**HTML**

```
  <router-outlet name="dashboard-outlet"></router-outlet>
```

**Routing TS**

```
const routes: Routes = [{ path: '', component: ComponentName, outlet: 'dashboard-outlet' }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i have used in the past.

```html
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar>
  <span
    mat-tab-link
    *ngFor="let routeLink of routeLinks; let i = index"
    [routerLink]="nav.link"
    routerLinkActive
    #rla="routerLinkActive"
    [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }"
    [active]="rla.isActive"
  >
    {{ routeLink.label }}
  </span>
</nav>

<div class="container my-3">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```